# how to minimise delay when we are accessing data in REACT from rest api. it takes 2-3 sec or more to get the data from api

Tags: reactjs

how to minimize delay when we are accessing data in REACT from rest api,
it takes 2-3 sec or more to get the data from api. i was facing an issue
when i was fetching data from ajax after completion of loading of my app it takes 2-3 second to get data in the dom.

how to minimize this delay